# Publishing image with docker from gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I am trying to create my war artifact with gradle and push it to my remote image repo. But the problem is it I am getting

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder756634785/build/libs/myartifact.war: no such file or directory.
```

So, It cannot reach to my artifact

how can I point to the correct location?

```java
//gitlab-ci.yaml

stages:
  - build

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.caching=true"
  
build:
  image: gradle:alpine
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build -i
    
docker_build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t myrepo.io/myimage:latest .
    - docker login myrepo.io -u username -p pass
    - docker push myrepo.io/myimage:latest
```

Comment: `myartifact.war` created by `./greadle clean build -i` command? In what stage you receive your error (build or docker_build)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your artifact that you generated in the `build` job and after that you will be able to download it on the `docker_build` job (using dependency)

In this doc you have a lot of examples about how to handle it https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

and look at this example: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies